# Augmented Reality in windows phone use phonegap

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, plugins, augmented-reality, native-code

I want to use augmented reality!
But phonegap plugins don't exist (I have not found.)! =(
Does anyone else with this problem?
Possible as that can switch between projects in the application (with phonegap code to the native code)?

I know for iOS and Android plugins exist!

Thanks!

Comment: Google first? http://www.wikitude.com/developer/get-started/phonegap

Comment: Available for iOS and Android. Please read them carefully!!! I need a plugin for Windows Phone!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SLAR Toolkit](http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/). If PhoneGap doesn't cut it because of a lacking plugin, you can always design your application without it (aka standard Windows Phone Application Project in Visual Studio).

Comment: Yes, but this is only part of the application. I just think that it is possible to include it as another application in PhoneGap. I just have not found the answer yet ....

Comment: Certainly possible - you can write your own plugin.